# Racket with-handlers not working as expected

Tags: racket

I'm trying to determining whether a TCP port is open or not. To do so, i've wrote the following code(i'm using `with-handlers` to handle exceptions):

```rkt
#lang racket

(define (port-open? host port)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail:network? (lambda (exp) #f)])
    (tcp-connect host port))
  #t)
(port-open? "127.0.0.1" 70)
```

The problem is, the function always returns `#t` even if the selected port is closed.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The last expression of `port-open?` is `#t`, so that's what it always returns...

Comment: You also should close the ports returned by `tcp-connect`.

Comment: @Shawn If I remove it, I cannot return true in case of success.

Comment: You don't so much remove it as move it to a more appropriate location.

Comment: I guess you expect this to be roughly equivalent to (pseudo-C++) `try { tcp_connect(host, port); } catch (network_exception) { return false; } return true; `, but it isn't. It's more like `try { tcp_connect(host, port); } catch (network_exception) { false; } return true;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `#t` is the last expression in the body of `port-open?`, it gets returned every time you call the function. You need to move it inside the `with-handlers` so it only returns when the body of that expression executes normally (And close the ports returned by `tcp-connect` to prevent resource leaks, too):

```lisp
(define (port-open? host port)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail:network? (lambda (exp) #f)])
    (let-values ([(reader writer) (tcp-connect host port)])
      (close-input-port reader)
      (close-output-port writer)
      #t)))
```